# Makefile clean on windows

Tags: windows, makefile

I'm learning about using makefiles now and I made the following makefile (I'm on windows using visual studio command line compiler)

```
CC = cl
CFLAG = /EHsc
test_database.exe: composer.obj database.obj test_database.obj
    $(CC) test_database.obj database.obj composer.obj
test_database.obj: test_database.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c test_database.cpp
composer.obj: composer.cpp composer.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c composer.cpp
database.obj: database.cpp database.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c database.cpp

.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm -f *.obj
```

Whenever I invoke `make clean` I get `make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc00000fd, addr = 0x4ff283)`
I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I can use make to compile the program no problem I just get the error when I target clean. `rm` exists on my machine and is on the path as I use it all the time. I've tried it with `DEL` as well with an identical error. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Make Version is `GNU Make 3.80`

Comment: Well, you seem to be applying GNU makefile knowledge to Nmake, assuming you're invoking Nmake using `make` on the command line instead of a build of GNU make for Windows.  You have a typo on line 2 (`CFLAG` should be `CFLAGS`), but other than that, it should just be a matter of removing the .PHONY directive that Nmake doesn't support and changing `rm -f` to `del /f /q`.

Comment: `make --version` gives me `GNU Make 3.80`, thanks for noticing the typo though but that's just an error handling option to the compiler unrelated to the clean. I've done it with both the phony there and omitted.

Comment: What version of `make` is this?  `make --version` ought to tell you.  `make -p clean` may also help.

Comment: @Chrono Kitsune that is the answer - post it - and it should be upvoted and accepted

Answer (score 2):

The makefile you have is fine, "nmake clean" correctly invokes the command.

The version on make you are using is not working. Your options is to either use nmake.exe utility that comes with Visual Studio or Windows SDK or get a version of make that works.

Comment: But I can use the `make` utility to compile just fine, the whole make isn't broken or unavailable, my question is just related to the error being thrown when I `make clean` and I ONLY get this error when I make clean. Thanks for the tip about using nmake instead but I still want to know why make clean is failing.

Comment: It looks like make clean is failing due to the way the GNU make (as part of msys) invokes the rm command. Even though rm works when run by itself, it does nor work when run from make. If you use nmake then rm will work, but you may run into other differences between nmake and make which could break your makefile.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in make, caused by parantheses in your PATH variable. See http://okolovich.info/interruptexception-caught-with-code-0xc00000fd/

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I faced the same problem. In my case it appears that escaping an asterisk (that is `rm -rf \*.obj`) solved the problem. Though my make version is a bit newer: `GNU Make 3.81`.