# Dev-Cpp "make.exe" error code = 0xc00000fd

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, mingw

This is the log I received from Dev-Cpp when I tried to compile a program:

```
 Compiler: Default compiler
 Building Makefile: "C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win"
 Executing  make...
 make.exe -f "C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win" all
 make.exe: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc00000fd, addr = 0x4ff283)

 Execution terminated
```

I have googled for the answer, I've tried the "PATH" fix, and make my MINGW stuff first like this.

```
 C:\Dev-Cpp\mingw32\bin;C:\Dev-Cpp\bin;
```

Yet I still can't compile, I've even restarted my computer (Windows 7 x64), and still the same error. So I'm wondering if you guys have any answers that can help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider [using](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2831140&group_id=10639&atid=110639) Google, or [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222371/makefile-clean-on-windows), which leads you [here](http://okolovich.info/interruptexception-caught-with-code-0xc00000fd/).

Comment: Find a better development environment?  Dev-C++ looks pretty poor to me...

Comment: @Christian.K I did, I googled for 3 hours, tried ALL of the possible ways to fix it, and still nada, that's why I'm asking here to see if anyone who uses Dev-Cpp encountered this error and managed to fix it.

Comment: @Nom did you also try the "run as administrator" fix as indicated in the first [link](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2831140&group_id=10639&atid=110639)?

Comment: Cannot answer your question, but as someone who was trying to use Dev-Cpp for work I can tell you there are way better and more up to date IDEs available. Dev-Cpp is seriously outdated.

Answer (score 3):

1. I have used the old Dev-C++ in the past and I've have had it break randomly on me at times.. *(crucial times I might add)*.
2. Bloodshed Dev-C++ hasn't been updated for years and development has actually stopped on it.
3. If you really like the environment consider getting the updated and maintained [Orwell Dev C++](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com/) that is improved, faster and much cleaner.

Comment: I'll try this out and report back.

Comment: @iKlsR: wow, thanks for pointing wxDev-C++ out. Looks like a very promising project. I used to work with wxWidgets when it was still called wxWindows and back in those days you had to buy the designers for dialogs :) ... +1

Answer (score 2):

No additional PATH is normally needed for compilation with Dev-CPP.

Seems to be a very old Dev-CPP version. My version neither has a `\Dev-Cpp\bin` directory, nor a `Makefile.win` in the main location. Maybe your installation is defective.

Did you install the compiler system along with Dev-CPP (and make executeable).

Please remove everything and use a modern, [up to date version of DevCpp](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.de/) for 32 or 64 bit.

- [Dev-CPP 32bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/files/Setup%20Releases/Dev-Cpp%205.2.0.3%20MinGW32%20Setup.exe/download)
- [Dev-CPP 64bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/files/Setup%20Releases/Dev-Cpp%205.2.0.3%20TDM-GCC%20x64%20Setup.exe/download)

One hint: Do not install DevCpp into a directiory with `' '` spaces, like `/Program Files/` etc. Better, use `C:\Apps\Dev-Cpp` or sth. like that.

#### Addendum

To the critics who say "*Dev-Cpp is very old, drop it*". No, thats wrong. Dev-Cpp is imho actually the best free IDE/Compiler system for Windows - and I have a lot of them installed (Netbeans, CodeBlocks, VS2010, VS2012rc, dropped Eclipse/CDT). Please have a [look here ...](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.de/)
Dev-Cpp retains the simplicity of the early Turbo-Compiler and connects that with 32/64bit gcc 4.6. Although I use VS2010/12rc for serious development, I always create the projects in parallel for Dev-Cpp in order to get gcc compatibility.

Regards

rbo

Comment: I'll try downloading the linked version and report back.

Comment: Rubber Boots, I now receive this error:

     Compiler: TDM-GCC 4.6.1 64-bit
Building Makefile "C:\Dev-cpp\projects\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
mingw32-make.exe -f "C:\Dev-cpp\projects\Makefile.win" all
mingw32-make.exe: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc0000005, addr = 0x0x752143f9)

Execution terminated
:: Note(I installed it into a directory I called Dev-Cpp, in the C:\)

Comment: Probably related to [this](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?25412). Could you please add the content of your `%PATH%` variable to your posting above?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps recursion problem in macro expansion.

```
Makefile:

rtest=$(info $(words $1))$(call rtest,$1 1)</b>
$(info $(call rtest))
# eof Makefile

yields :
2152
2153
mingw32-make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc00000fd, addr = 0x00007ffdbdea2f57)
2154
```

Comment: But you realize that you answer a platform-specific question that is almost 9 years old :-) ?